# Pgsql - Pivot table with unkown number of columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot-table

I am trying to create and return a pivot table in a pgsql function. The issue I am having is that the number of columns to be returned by the function is dependant on what date range the user chooses.

I currently am using the colpivot function (https://github.com/hnsl/colpivot/blob/master/README.md) and this works fine in standard queries but not in a function because the return type needs to be set at call time.

### **Approach**

### Step 1:

```
create  temp table _test (
dt timestamp without time zone, id integer,  NumericValue numeric
)
```

### Step 2:

```
insert into _test(dt , id ,NumericValue)
SELECT DISTINCT "T03017_PSR_LOG"."DateTime", 
    "T03017_PSR_LOG"."ID",
    "T03017_PSR_LOG"."NumericValue"
FROM "T03017_PSR_LOG"
INNER JOIN "T03002_PSR_TAG_REG" ON "T03017_PSR_LOG"."TagID" = "T03002_PSR_TAG_REG"."TagID"
WHERE "T03017_PSR_LOG"."DateTime" > 2018-10-02 AND "T03017_PSR_LOG"."DateTime" < 2018-10-07,    
ORDER BY "DateTime", "ID";
```

### Step 3:

```
select colpivot('_test_pivoted', 'select * from _test', array['tagid'], array['dt'], '#.numericvalue', null);

select * from _test_pivoted order by tagid;
```

If I run the above as a standard query it will return something like:

```
ID   2018-10-03   2018-10-04   2018-10-05   2018-10-06

10   1405717.00   1453189.00   1499992.00   1546791.00
11   359102.00    371282.00    383042.00    395047.00
```

I need something like the above table to return from a function, where the datetime range would be 2 variables passed into the function, however I cant seem to find a solution for this as I'm not sure how to set the return type at the top of the function due to the dynamic nature of the returned columns.

Comment: Have you tried the crosstab function https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html ? You might be able to avoid installing extensions if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This may look a little klugy, but I don't know of any way to return a variable number of columns, and I think your best bet is to use arrays.

Without any knowledge of your data, I can only assume you have data gaps, meaning not every id has a datapoint for every date, so the first task I would do is fill in the gaps and determine every possible combination of dates and IDs.

```
with all_dates as (
  select distinct dt from _test
),
all_ids as (
  select distinct id from _test
)
select id, dt
from all_dates
cross join all_ids
```

From there, I'd join that back to the original dataset so that every element in every row's array refers to the same thing (ie if element #5 from one row is November of 2017, then it means that for every row).

Here is what the entire query looks like:

```
with all_dates as (
  select distinct dt from _test
),
all_ids as (
  select distinct id from _test
),
all_combo as (
  select id, dt
  from all_dates
  cross join all_ids
),
pivot_data as (
  select
    a.dt, a.id, coalesce (t.NumericValue, 0) as NumericValue
  from
    all_combo a
    left join _test t on
      a.id = t.id and
      a.dt = t.dt
  order by
    a.id, a.dt
)
select
  id, array_agg(NumericValue) as valuez
from pivot_data
group by id
```

It would be a little repetitious (same values on every row), but you could also include the date range as an array:

```
select
  id, array_agg(dt) as dates, array_agg(NumericValue) as valuez
```